# how to bind the containing element in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

I have a `RadGridView` which has a context menu and in this context menu I have a button which I set a command on in the parameters I want to pass the gridview itself - how do I do this?

```
<telerik:RadGridView Height="620" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="radGridView2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1564" ShowGroupPanel="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}" BorderBrush="#FFD7D2D2" FontFamily="Mangal" FontSize="14" Loaded="radGridView2_Loaded" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             RowStyleSelector="{StaticResource rowStyleSelector}" GroupRenderMode="Flat" ShowColumnSortIndexes="True" CanUserFreezeColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                             DataContext="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" DataLoading="radGridView2_DataLoading" DataLoaded="radGridView2_DataLoaded" GroupPanelForeground="#FFF01D1D"
                             ShowColumnFooters="True" ShowGroupFooters="True" AutoExpandGroups="True" GridLinesVisibility="Both" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,35,0" MouseDoubleClick="radGridView2_MouseDoubleClick" 
                             ColumnWidth="52*">
            <telerik:RadGridView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.Items>
                        <Button Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <TextBlock Text="Print"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </ContextMenu.Items>
                </ContextMenu>
            </telerik:RadGridView.ContextMenu>
         </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Using `{Binding}` as my `CommandParameter` does not work it gives me the row in which I click - the data context of that row - which is some business object - how do I get the containing grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean with 'containing grid' the `RadGridView` try

```
CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
```

You will need the `PlacementTarget` property because `ContextMenu` has its own VisualTree.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeSource to bind to the parent element data context:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}}"
```

Comment: the parameter is still `null`